# How can I create terraform aws_security_group with multiple eip and ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create the instances according to the following code -

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami = "ami-0fe0b2cf0e1f25c8a"
  instance_type = var.ec2_instance_type
  count = var.number_of_instances

  tags = {
    Name = "ec2_instance_${count.index}"
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  vpc = true
  count = var.number_of_instances
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eic_assoc" {
  instance_id = aws_instance.ec2[count.index].id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb[count.index].id
  count = var.number_of_instances
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name = "first-security-group-created-by-terraform"
  count = var.number_of_instances
  ingress {
      from_port = var.security_group_port
      to_port = var.security_group_port
      protocol = var.security_group_protocol
      cidr_blocks = ["${aws_eip.lb[count.index].public_ip}/32"]
  }
}
```

And got the following error -

> Error: creating Security Group (first-security-group-created-by-terraform): InvalidGroup.Duplicate: The security group 'first-security-group-created-by-terraform' already exists for VPC 'vpc-0fb3457c89d86e916'

Probably because this is not the right way to create the aws_security_group when there are multiple instances of eip and ec2.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple security groups, but giving them all exactly the same name. The name needs to be unique for each security group. You could fix it like this:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  count = var.number_of_instances
  name  = "first-security-group-created-by-terraform-${count.index}"
  ingress {
      from_port = var.security_group_port
      to_port = var.security_group_port
      protocol = var.security_group_protocol
      cidr_blocks = ["${aws_eip.lb[count.index].public_ip}/32"]
  }
}
```

---

One way to create a single security group with multiple ingress rules is to create the group without any `ingress` blocks, and then create the ingress rules separately:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name  = "first-security-group-created-by-terraform"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_tls_rules" {
  count = var.number_of_instances

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.security_group_port
  to_port           = var.security_group_port
  protocol          = var.security_group_protocol
  cidr_blocks       = ["${aws_eip.lb[count.index].public_ip}/32"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_tls.id
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! what if I want to put all the eip instances under the same security group? @Mark B